# Experimental realization of rectangular potential barrier

Tags: quantum-mechanics, electric-circuits, electricity, potential, electronics

I was reading a QM book where they put the following figure aiming to explain how to realize experimentally a potential barrier/well. In the left (barrier) and right (well) plots they show a circuit in which, as we go from left to right, we will measure a potential as they show in the plot below the circuit. The cylinders are made with a metallic material. My problem is: I don't know how to derive the potential vs position plots shown. Can anyone help me?
[image]

Comment: Can you elaborate on your difficulty? For example, is it clear in the left-hand picture that the cylinder on the left is grounded while the cylinder on the right is at a potential $V_0$?

Comment: You can approximate the gaps as parallel-plate capacitors of infinite area, in which case the potential changes linearly in the gap.  By "relaxing" the approximation of infinite area a little bit, the potential will round out at the edges, yielding what you've got here.  Basically, look up the electric potential of a parallel plate capacitor.